# posting complex data and the object returning null when pass to controller in asp.net mvc by ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am posting complex data and the object returning null when passing to controller in asp.net mvc by ajax

Below is my code that is returning null

```
//Ajax Call
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $rootScope.settings.webApis.RealTimeAIAPIService.url,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(realTimeAIConfig),
        }).done(function (result, response) {
            if (response == "success") { }
 });

//Controller Method
  [HttpPost]

  [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]

  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(RealTimeAIConfig realTimeAIConfig)

  {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)

        {

          return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        try
        {

            if (realTimeAIConfig.ID != 1)
            {
               _RealTimeAIConfigService.CreateAsync(realTimeAIConfig);
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return Created(realTimeAIConfig);
    }
```

what can I do to avoid it returning null?

Comment: `console.log(realTimeAIConfig)` and show us what the object contains.

Comment: Probably not going to get much help unless you post your model and expand on how you are generating your realTimeAIConfig js object...

Answer (score 0):

I have some issues with complex object and what I do was create a simple class and pass map the field that i only need. When the object is to complex the value will be null. Hope this will help